# php date into mysql Date

Tags: php, mysql, date

Why is the mysql date field not being updated?

```
$st =   $this->db->prepare("update users set ipaddress=? and 
lastlogin=? where     email=?"); 
$mysqldate  =   date('Y-m-d');                          
$st->execute(array($ip_address, $mysqldate, $email));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without the "and" which is incorrect in case of updating:

```
$st =   $this->db->prepare("update users set ipaddress=?, lastlogin=? where     email=?");
```

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html

Other than that, you could use the mysql time functions, for example **CURDATE()** to achieve your result: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate